# How do I switch between two apps seamlessly?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, prism-4

I have a .NET application that was written in C# and VB.NET using WinForms. We want to slowly migrate this to something new, in many iterations. The new code will be entirely C# and WPF. We would like to utilize Prism.

As far as I know, we can't integrate the old WinForm app in Prism.

I am considering making my old app show the new app in certain instances. For example, when you press a tab in the old app, the new app opens on top of the old app, with the same tabs. Over time, only the new app would be necessary.

How can I do this?

Comment: Gross. Do not do this. Just rewrite it in WPF...it should take a few weeks

Comment: It is gross... but I don't have the luxury of rewriting... and it certainly would not take a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my comment above if you HAVE to do this hack I would start creating WPF Controls and ViewModels and integrate then in WinForms. So your slowly replacing Forms in your Winforms app with WPF Control, Pages, and Windows. [Here is a tutorial to get you started](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms)

Keep in mind you should be creating a WPF during the side at the same time. That way when your like 85% done you can just concentrate on the WPF app.

Comment: Thank you. Great plan. Will do.